# Application of Min & Max function

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, sklearn-pandas

My goal is to normalize my data (minimization & Maximization) for machine learning purposes. The issue I am having is presented when you run the code below.

```python
#importation of libraries:
import pandas as pd     
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
# for normalization  
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

    # Data
    data = {"1":[1,2,3,4], "2":[20,60,70,34]}
    
    # training Data Frame compilation
    tr_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    tr_df
    
    # define a function to perform min-max normalization
    def df_normalize(df,i=3):
             #apply min-max_scaler to each rows\n",
             #since min-max scaler originally applies to columns, \n",
             #we will use transposed data and then update the data with transposed result
            
             min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
             df.iloc[:,i:] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df.iloc[:,i:].T).T
    
    tr_df.describe().round(2) # Summarizes data
```

Comment: Can you describe what the issue is that you are having? Is there an error code you can supply?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to run your function `df_normalize()`, passing `tr_df` to it, which gives you the following error:

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 4)) while a minimum of 1 is required by MinMaxScaler.
```

In your function definition `def df_normalize(df,i=3)`, why having `i=3` there? You `data` only has 2 columns.

Could be simplified and replaced by:

```
def df_normalize(df):
    min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
    df[df.columns] = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(df[df.columns])

print(tr_df.describe().round(2))

df_normalize(tr_df)
tr_df
```

And adding the `df_normalize(tr_df)` call at the end of your code, which outputs:

```
          1      2
count  4.00   4.00
mean   2.50  46.00
std    1.29  23.04
min    1.00  20.00
25%    1.75  30.50
50%    2.50  47.00
75%    3.25  62.50
max    4.00  70.00

    1           2
0   0.000000    0.00
1   0.333333    0.80
2   0.666667    1.00
3   1.000000    0.28
```

Which I assume is what you wanted to get as result. Note the MinMax normalization making sense here, with `1 (min) --> 0.0` and `70 (max) -> 1.00`